# Should I be getting this warning "you're in danger of being blocked" and should my second question be marked as a dup?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

Edit: Would appear my dup has been removed and thus fixing the problem with the warning.

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

I'm getting this warning whenever I want to ask a question, and after almost 2 years on StackOverflow I've never had that warning. It is quite scary. It makes me feel like I do not ask good questions.

However, I don't think that I should be getting that warning. Here are my reasons why.

I've asked two questions ever since my arrival on this stackexchange, and they've both been marked as duplicates to the same question.

1. My first question [Where can I stay once I get a private visa invitation from my Russian friend](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62777/where-can-i-stay-once-i-get-a-private-visa-invitation-from-my-russian-friend) was marked as a duplicate to this question: [Do you need to submit an itinerary to get a Russian visa? And do you have to stick to it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/447/do-you-need-to-submit-an-itinerary-to-get-a-russian-visa-and-do-you-have-to-sti) While I admit it does answer my question, in my defense I would have never found that question with it's current title.
2. My second question, I asked a specific question regarding `airbnb` and `visatorussia` [How does a tourist visa from VisaToRussia with Airbnb work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/63857/how-does-a-touristic-visa-from-visatorussia-with-airbnb-work) and it still got marked as a dup to the same post as my first question [Do you need to submit an itinerary to get a Russian visa? And do you have to stick to it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/447/do-you-need-to-submit-an-itinerary-to-get-a-russian-visa-and-do-you-have-to-sti) . Why? Why would I have asked a dup after thoroughly reading *that post that does not answer my question*?

Any clarity on this would be greatful.

Comment: I just found this, but it looks like your second one is still open and is not a dupe? Am I missing something?

Comment: In fact you answered it a week ago?

Comment: @MarkMayo it would seem Relaxed reoponed it today (check the edits). Yes I answered it a week ago. It was marked as dup right after I answered. I wasn't going to say anything because in the end I found my answer. Yesterday I wanted to ask a new question, but I saw the warning indicating my account may be blocked. That's why I made this post regarding all this.

Comment: Bizarre. Well it's just an automated warning, not a community one, I guess all I can suggest is to be extra vigilant for a bit that any new questions aren't dupes and that they meet the [help] criteria. I'm sure you'll be fine though :D

Comment: @MarkMayo well ever since Relaxed removed the dup, the warning is gone.. so I guess that solves the problem. :)

Comment: Arrghhhh..... I'm just going to leave this here: [Can we be more careful in marking duplicates on questions that are related but ask for or about different things?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/can-we-be-more-careful-in-marking-duplicates-on-questions-that-are-related-but-a) maybe some people are still treating the close queue like a competition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of an A, copying a Comment:

> well ever since Relaxed removed the dup, the warning is gone.. so I guess that solves the problem. :) – rugdealer Feb 23 at 13:41